# How can I add floating label to react-select?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I'm trying to build web app using [MaterialUI theme](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-react) and I need to use autocomplete .. It turns out MUI v2 does not have AutoComplete and docs suggest using alternatives. react-select has all functionality I need - but I cannot figure out how to make it look similarly to other controls - specifically how to make floating label to float away when user starts typing or click on dropdown.

What I did:

- created a component (IntegratedSelect) that uses react-select  from [this demo](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/demos/autocomplete/IntegrationReactSelect.js)
- cloned [this file](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard-react/blob/master/src/components/CustomInput/CustomInput.jsx) into CustomAutocomplete.jsx and replaced `<Input>` with `<IntegratedSelect>`
- modified code to pass id to IntegratedSelect and set that id to Select control

.. and tried a lot of different other approaches (setting refs, using FloatingLabel from @material/react-floating-label etc).. with no luck.

Can you please advise how can I trigger float on the label, or otherwise hookup react-select control with floating label?
Any help will be appreciated!

Regards,
VB

---

P.S. Gist added: https://gist.github.com/mspclaims/e07bf1ff657fa8eb4756bc0514a164fe

Comment: Can you share relevant code?

Comment: I updated post to include link to gist with source code and screenshot. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 4):

Following [this comment](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4221#issuecomment-700617916) on a similar issue on GitHub, I was able to get it to work! In my case, I'm using `styled-component` but it should work regardless of the styling used

```js
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { components } from "react-select";

export const Control = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Label isFloating={props.isFocused || props.hasValue}>Select</Label>
      <components.Control {...props} />
    </>
  );
};

const Label = styled.label<{ isFloating?: boolean }>`
  left: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  z-index: 1;

  top: ${(props) => (props.isFloating ? `5px` : `35%`)};
  font-size: ${(props) => (props.isFloating ? `0.5rem` : `1rem`)};
`;
```

You can add your custom control component to Select:

```js
<Select 
  ...
  components={{ Control }} 
  placeholder=""
/>
```

**NOTE: You must ensure your Select component doesn't have an empty default value otherwise, `hasValue` will always be true**